# React Native - how to key number pad ONLY (without punctuations)

Tags: react-native, keyboard, numeric

Is there a way to key a numeric keypad without punctuations?

```
<TextInput keyboardType='numeric' ..... />
```

if I use `secureTextEntry={true}`, it gets the right keyboard I want, but the values are replaced with `*`.

so, this is what im getting:

[image]

This is what I want:

[image]

Comment: the `phone-pad` btw generates `pause`, `wait` etc keys, so thats not the answer

Answer (score 19):

I had the same problem.

I could solve doing something like this:

```
keyboardType={Device.isAndroid ? "numeric" : "number-pad"}
```

and then in a method call from `onChangeText` doing this:

```
const cleanNumber = number.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

this.setState({
  cleanNumber
});
```

and it the value prop of TextInput

```
value={this.state.cleanNumber}
```

Comment: You could use this regex `const cleanNumber = text.replace(/\D/g, "");` for much neater way.

Answer (score 4):

keyboardType={"number-pad"} Works on Android.
Note: I am using FormInput from react-native-elements.

Comment: Note: "number-pad" only works in android from react-native version 0.56 or higher.

Comment: @DrorBar, actually in 0.66.x version it doesn't work, I don't know if is a kind of error, but...

Answer (score 3):

React native not provided `keyboardType` which remove punctuation from keyboard. You need to use regular expression with replace method to remove punctuation from text and set `keyboardType = 'numeric'`.

**Regular Expression**

> /[- #*;,.<>{}[]\/]/gi

**Example code**

```
 onTextChanged(value) {
    // code to remove non-numeric characters from text
    this.setState({ number: value.replace(/[- #*;,.<>\{\}\[\]\\\/]/gi, '') });
  }
```

Please check snack link

https://snack.expo.io/@vishal7008/numeric-keyboard

Answer (score 2):

Did you try `number-pad`? both `number-pad` and `numeric` work for me on iOS.

Comment: im NOT building an IOS-only app!

Comment: Not supported in Ipad for some reason (haven't tested on Tablet).

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support keyboardType without  punctuations [A visual guide to the React Native TextInput keyboardType prop values](https://lefkowitz.me/visual-guide-to-react-native-textinput-keyboardtype-options/)

Answer (score 1):

For Android in my case I prevent set any special char with [Miguel Cardenas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55735799/10198605) example.

Here what I did:

```
const inputRef = useRef(null);
const setRefValue = v => {
      const clean = v.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');
      inputRef.current.value = clean;
      inputRef.current.setNativeProps({ text: clean });
    }
  };

<TextInput
   ref={inputRef}
   keyboardType={numeric}
   onChangeText={setRefValue}
/>
```

Every time type in TextInput the constant `setRefValue` will clean special characters.

Comment: But fraction of second value display then clean, it's not good. How to make input like phonepe and Google pay after qr scan, when we type hyphen doesn't happen like that way we want in react native.